Reference ngForm between ng-content blocks and outside form
I am using a component on which there are 2  elements. In one I inject a form like so:
<form #form="ngForm">

In the other I have buttons on which I'd like to use form.valid and form.pristine like this:
<button [disabled]="!form.valid || form.pristine">

This does not work since the button lives outside the form itself and in a separate ng-content element (that part might be irrelevant).
I've tried using:
@ViewChild('form') form!: ngForm

Unfortunately, this ends up as undefined.
Thanks!

use @ViewChild('form',{static:true}) form!: ngForm if your form is not under a *ngIf. The static:true makes that check if exist in the very first time the component is (this is the reason,e.g. you can use in ngOnInit but not check if exist never more -so if it's under a *ngIf will be "undefined" forever-

This is good to know! My form is not under an *ngIf currently, but this is great info for future use!

You are on the right track, we can just do a view child, but the value will get set only on ngAfterViewInit, so we can store the reference to the viewchild on a service variable, then use this variable to lookup the values on our not related component
Create a service:
export class SomeService {
    refForm!: Form;
}

In the component where the form is located
@ViewChild('form', {static: false}) form!: ngForm; 
...

...
constructor(private someService: SomeService) {}
...

...
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.someService.refForm = this.form;
}
...

Finally, in the component where you project the content for the button
in the TS file add the getter method which will relay the form for checking
...

...
constructor(private someService: SomeService) {}
...

...
get form() {
    return this.someService.refForm;
}

component html ( Make sure to add the safe check ?. so that there are no errors if the form is undefined! )
<button [disabled]="!form?.valid || form?.pristine">


This put me on right track. Adding the safe check ? resolved my issue.
